# Does shaking a jug of milk impact its longevity

Tags: food-safety, milk, spoilage

With some products like non-homogenous milk and ciders with precipitate its desireable to give the jug one or two sharp shakes for consistency. But I've found myself habitually doing this even for homogenized milk that doesn't need it, and was wondering if this had any negative effect.

My concern was to what extent the introduction of oxygen impact the flavor and longevity of the milk. Short-term, this does make the milk a bit foamier, but does this also accelerate spoilage? Are there any other advantages or downsides to this habit?

I've found an [article](https://justrestaurantsupplies.com/should-you-shake-milk/) on the subject of shaking that confirms there's no nutritional impact but there's no details on the impact of aeration--possibly because its a non-issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While aeration in industrial milk production is a tool used to impact flavor, I doubt a quick shake of your milk jug has much influence at all during the time that you are consuming it.